# How to run RF scripts using Github along with Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, robotframework

In my company earlier we have executed RF scripts in Jenkins via Github. Now they have moved to Azure Devops.

I am new to Azure Devops. Could some provide the steps for the configuration and how to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description , it seems that your Source Code is on Github.

Here are the steps to run the RF scripts:

1. Create a pipeline and use the repo from Github resource. You may need to create the connection to Github, then you could get the repos.

[image: Repo Source]

2. Add `Use Python Version` task to specify the required python version.
3. Install the  Robot framework dependencies with `Powershell task` or `Command Line Task`.
4. Run the RF script with `Powershell task` or `Command Line Task`.

For example: Yaml Editor

```
trigger:
- master

jobs:

- job: 'Test'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.7'
      architecture: 'x64'

  - script: pip install robotframework robotframework-seleniumlibrary && npm install chromedriver
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'
  
  - powershell: robot --pythonpath . -x outputxunit.xml TestCases.robot
    displayName: 'Run Robot Scripts'
```

If you want to use Pipeline Classic Editor, you could refer to [this blog](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/frosting-robot-framework-rainbow-cake-azure-devops-ana%C3%AFs-van-asselt).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin! Great documentation!